# Java pong ball not moving in the other direction when hitting the paddle

Tags: java

i am trying to make the game Pong in Java. Now i have a problem with the collision on the paddle. It is not moving the other direction. It does work when it hits the sides of the panel.

For now i just needs to go the other way when it hits the X value of the paddle.
I made a function to check the collision.

What am i doing wrong here. Can someone please explain me this?

Thanks in advance

```
public void checkCollision()
{
    if (ball.getY() == 0)
    {
        moveDown = true;
        moveUp = false;
    }
    if ((ball.getY() + ball.getHeight()) == height)
    {
        moveDown = false;
        moveUp = true;
    }
    if (ball.getX() == computer.getX())
    {
        moveRight = false;
        moveLeft = true;
    }
}
```

```java
class TimerHandler implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
        if (counter == 0) 
        {
            Random rand = new Random();
            int random = rand.nextInt(2) + 1 ;
            if (random == 1) 
            {
                moveUp = true;
                moveRight = true;
                counter++;
            }
            else if (random == 2) 
            {
                moveDown = true;
                moveLeft = true;
                counter++;
            }
        }
        controlMovement();
        checkCollision();
        repaint();
    }
}
```

Comment: You seem to have posted more code than what would be reasonable for your issue. Please read [ask] and how to make a [mcve], providing a MCVE helps users answer your question and future users relate to your issue.

Comment: The posted code is not [mcve]. " i have a problem with the collision on the paddle" : I don't see a paddle in the code posted.

Comment: Computer is one paddle

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your checkCollision function is incomplete... somehow, the function must have access to both paddle current positions to check if the ball hits one of the paddles...

Another suggestion is to use only one flag to indicante the movement in one axis, for example, `boolean monvingUp = true` indicantes that the ball is moving up at the Y-axis, when false, such flag indicates that is moving down at the Y-axis...

Comment: I was just checking one if it works. The other will come once i get one working

Answer (score 0):

I changed the = to > and it fixed the problem